# Localização atual - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Galera, preciso pegar a latitude e a longitude atual do celular coom flutter, porém nao esta funcionando e eu nao estou achando nada na internet, alguem pode me ajudar?

código:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(0, 0);
  static var location = new Location();
  var x = location.getLocation();
  var lg = x.longitude;
  var lt = x.latitude;


  final Set<Marker> _makers2 = {};

  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;

  static var latitudes = [-23.5629, -19.9324, -22.0154];
  static var longitudes = [-46.6544, -43.9388, -47.8911];
  static var i = 0;

  LatLng posicaoVetor = LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]);

  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  void _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _makers2.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]).toString()),
        position: LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
    i++;
  }

  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(0, 0), /*AQUI SERIA A LOCALIZAÇAO ATUAL DA PESSOA*/
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              markers: _makers2,
              onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.map, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onAddMarkerButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add_location, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tentou usar esse pacote e seguir os passos que estão na página? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando o plugin [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), você poderia fazer desta maneira:

```
void _getCurrentLocation() {
final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;
_geolocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus().then((GeolocationStatus _locationStatus) {
  if (_locationStatus == GeolocationStatus.granted) {
    _geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _stringPosition = 'Altitude: ${position.altitude} Longitude: ${position.longitude}';
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      _stringPosition = e.toString();
    });
  }
});
```

Onde primeiramente é solicitada a permissão para utilização da localização do dispositivo, com a permissão aceita você terá acesso a altitude, longitude e entre outros dados.

Para facilitar a leitura e observar como implementei estou deixando o link do projeto [Flutter-Geolocator](https://github.com/Josue10599/Flutter-Projects/tree/master/geolocation_flutter).

Answer (score 2):

Vi que você utiliza o `getLocation()` mas não utiliza seu valor, então tente algo assim:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(0, 0);
  static var location = new Location();
  /*var x = location.getLocation();
  var lg = x.longitude;
  var lt = x.latitude;*/

  var minhaLocalizacao;

  void pegarLocalizacao() async {
    setState((){
      minhaLocalizacao = await location.getLocation();
    })
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pegarLocalizacao();
  }

  final Set<Marker> _makers2 = {};

  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;

  static var latitudes = [-23.5629, -19.9324, -22.0154];
  static var longitudes = [-46.6544, -43.9388, -47.8911];
  static var i = 0;

  LatLng posicaoVetor = LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]);

  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  void _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _makers2.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]).toString()),
        position: LatLng(latitudes[i], longitudes[i]),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
    i++;
  }

  void _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(''),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(minhaLocalizacao.latitude, minhaLocalizacao.longitude),
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              markers: _makers2,
              onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.map, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onAddMarkerButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add_location, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Não se esqueça de seguir o passo a passo disponível na página do [package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/location#-readme-tab-)
que você está utilizando, pois é necessário pedir a permissão para utilizar o acesso fino à localização!

*Obs.: Estou sem o Flutter no computador em que me encontro, logo não testei nada!*

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizei dessa maneira utilizando o package [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location)
Serve para pegar a localização atual do GPS, verifica se é dada a permissão de GPS para o aplicativo, caso não tenha ele pede pra autorizar e depois pega a localização atual do aparelho.

```
try {
  Location location = new Location();
  bool permission = await checkPermission();

  if(permission) {

    await location.getLocation().then((onValue) {
      //print(onValue["latitude"].toString() + "," + onValue["longitude"].toString());
    });

    //print("Com permissões!");
    posicao = await location.getLocation().catchError((e){
      //print("ERRO DE LOCALIZAÇÃO: "+e.toString());
    });

    posicao = await location.onLocationChanged().first;
    //print("POSICAO TO STRING: " + posicao.toString());

    print("latitude: ${posicao["latitude"]} | longitude: ${posicao["longitude"]} | altitude: ${posicao["altitude"]}");
  } else {
    print("Sem permissões!");
  }
  return true;
} catch (e) {
  print("CATCH ERROR: ${e.toString()}");
}

Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    bool hasPermission =
    await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(Permission.WhenInUseLocation);

    //debugPrint("*location_state_handler* permission for location: $hasPermission");

    if (hasPermission) {
      return true;
    }

    PermissionStatus permissionStatus =
    await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WhenInUseLocation);

    debugPrint("permission request result is $permissionStatus");

    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.authorized ||
        permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.restricted) {
      return true;
    }

    print('permission denied');
    return false;
}
```